# Using Fiware Cygnus with mysql sink, no data base has been created

Tags: fiware, fiware-cygnus

I configured my cygnusagent to use mySQL sink as bellow and I used the notifcation script from the tutorial [1] to test it, but nothing has been changed in my data base, no new data base has been created.

Any ideas of what I may missed? Thanks!

```
cygnusagent.sources = http-source
cygnusagent.sinks = mysql-sink 
cygnusagent.channels = mysql-channel 

#=============================================
# source configuration
# channel name where to write the notification events
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.channels = mysql-channel 
# source class, must not be changed
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.type = org.apache.flume.source.http.HTTPSource
# listening port the Flume source will use for receiving incoming notifications
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.port = 5050
# Flume handler that will parse the notifications, must not be changed
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.handler = com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.handlers.OrionRestHandler
# URL target
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.handler.notification_target = /notify
# Default service (service semantic depends on the persistence sink)
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.handler.default_service = def_serv
# Default service path (service path semantic depends on the persistence sink)
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.handler.default_service_path = def_servpath
# Number of channel re-injection retries before a Flume event is definitely discarded (-1 means infinite retries)
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.handler.events_ttl = 10
# Source interceptors, do not change
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.interceptors = ts 
# TimestampInterceptor, do not change
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.interceptors.ts.type = timestamp
# GroupinInterceptor, do not change
#cygnusagent.sources.http-source.interceptors.gi.type = com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.interceptors.GroupingInterceptor$Builder
# Grouping rules for the GroupingInterceptor, put the right absolute path to the file if necessary
# See the doc/design/interceptors document for more details
#cygnusagent.sources.http-source.interceptors.gi.grouping_rules_conf_file = /usr/cygnus/conf/grouping_rules.conf

# ============================================
# OrionMySQLSink configuration
# channel name from where to read notification events
cygnusagent.sinks.mysql-sink.channel = mysql-channel
# sink class, must not be changed
cygnusagent.sinks.mysql-sink.type = com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.OrionMySQLSink
# the FQDN/IP address where the MySQL server runs
cygnusagent.sinks.mysql-sink.mysql_host = 192.168.1.107
# the port where the MySQL server listes for incomming connections
cygnusagent.sinks.mysql-sink.mysql_port = 3306
# a valid user in the MySQL server
cygnusagent.sinks.mysql-sink.mysql_username = root
# password for the user above
cygnusagent.sinks.mysql-sink.mysql_password = poiu
# how the attributes are stored, either per row either per column (row, column)
cygnusagent.sinks.mysql-sink.attr_persistence = row

#=============================================
# mysql-channel configuration
# channel type (must not be changed)
cygnusagent.channels.mysql-channel.type = memory
# capacity of the channel
cygnusagent.channels.mysql-channel.capacity = 1000
# amount of bytes that can be sent per transaction
cygnusagent.channels.mysql-channel.transactionCapacity = 100
```

Here is my cygnus logs after the reception of data:

```
15/07/16 16:42:34 INFO handlers.OrionRestHandler: Starting transaction (1437057740-95-0000000000)
15/07/16 16:42:34 INFO handlers.OrionRestHandler: Received data ({    "subscriptionId" : "51c0ac9ed714fb3b37d7d5a8",    "originator" : "localhost",    "contextResponses" : [        {            "contextElement" : {                "attributes" : [                    {                        "name" : "temperature",                        "type" : "centigrade",                        "value" : "26.5"                    }                ],                "type" : "Room",                "isPattern" : "false",                "id" : "Room1"            },            "statusCode" : {                "code" : "200",                "reasonPhrase" : "OK"            }        }    ]})
15/07/16 16:42:34 INFO handlers.OrionRestHandler: Event put in the channel (id=119782869, ttl=10)
15/07/16 16:42:34 INFO sinks.OrionSink: Event got from the channel (id=119782869, headers={content-type=application/json, fiware-service=room, fiware-servicepath=room, ttl=10, transactionId=1437057740-95-0000000000, timestamp=1437057754877}, bodyLength=612)
15/07/16 16:42:34 WARN sinks.OrionSink: 
15/07/16 16:42:34 INFO sinks.OrionSink: Finishing transaction (1437057740-95-0000000000)
```

[1] https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-cygnus/blob/release/0.8.2/doc/quick_start_guide.md

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have commented this part of the configuration file:

```
# GroupinInterceptor, do not change
#cygnusagent.sources.http-source.interceptors.gi.type = com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.interceptors.GroupingInterceptor$Builder
# Grouping rules for the GroupingInterceptor, put the right absolute path to the file if necessary
# See the doc/design/interceptors document for more details
#cygnusagent.sources.http-source.interceptors.gi.grouping_rules_conf_file = /usr/cygnus/conf/grouping_rules.conf
```

You must uncomment those parameters, even if you are not going to use the Grouping Rules feature (simply leave in blank `/usr/cygnus/conf/grouping_rules.conf`).